# React-Router <Redirect> doesn't work on top level inside App.js which defines <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My `<Redirect/>` works correctly on all components **under** my **App.js**, which defines the `<Router>` structure.

For example, if I have `<SomeComponent>` somewhere down below, this correctly redirects to `/error` in case of errors:

*SomeComponent.js*

```
return (<>      
    {
        error.message && <Redirect to="/error" />
    }
```

But on the top-level in **App.js** I also need to check for errors and redirect if necessary. This is where I also define the core `<Router>` structure. For some reason this top-level redirect does **not** work:

*App.js*

```
return (<>
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                {/* I am inside Router, so there shouldn't be any issues */}

                {/* Check for errors and redirect as usual */}
                {
                   error.message && <Redirect to="/error" />
                }      

                <Main /> {/* The <Main> component has Switch/Route */}
          
            </Router>
        </div>
       );
```

Any idea why? FYI, Router is defined as `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"`.

Comment: Where do you have the Route for /error?

Comment: you have no any error message,just not working?

Comment: I have `Switch..Route` in a component called `<Main>` which is under the App component. Maybe that's why it's not working, actually.

Comment: That should be the issue, with the Redirect being outside of the Switch Route.